# create templates on the fly / dynamically

Tags: python, django, django-templates, dry

I am currently writing a django app around a rather complex data model.
For many use cases, I need to build similar, but slightly differing templates (incl. graphviz etc..).

Now I wonder if there is a way to follow DRY and create the templates "on the fly", e.g. based on a nested tuple (of which one gets defined per use-case -> template).

Practically speaking I'd like to stop writing these:

**static_template_case1.html**

```
{% if program %}
    {{ program.name }}
    {% for process in program.process_set.all %}
        {{ process.name }}
        {% for step in process.step_set.all %}
            {{ step.name }}
        {% endfor %}
        {% for control in process.control_set.all %}
            {{ control.name }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

and replace it with something in the following direction:

**template_generator.py**

```
structure_case1 = ("program"("process"("step","control")))

def onTheFlyTemplate(structure):
    # iterate through structure
    # build template dynamically
    # return template

onTheFlyTemplate(structure_case1)
```

I was not able to find something similar and also don't know yet where to start generating templates on the fly, nor how to integrate it.

Within the views feels like a good starting point, (instead of `loader.get_template('static_template_case1.html')`).

Thanks for any hint sending me into the right direction as well as your thoughts if DRY is being "overdone" here.

Ralph

## Edit

I got a step closer, doing the following:

In the view:

```
from django.template import Template
def templateGen():
    return Template("Program: {{program.count}}") 

@login_required
def test(request):
    program = Program.objects.all()
    t = templateGen()
    c = RequestContext(request,locals())
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

So far this is only a proof of concept. The real work will be to write a smart "templateGen()" listening to the nested tuple.

Comment: Funny, now seven years later I have a similar idea to a nice solution, in the meantime using Jinja2. And google brings me back this question I asked last time (Django). :-)

Answer (score 2):

How about an inclusion tag?

```
@register.inclusion_tag('<your-template.html>')
    def get_program(program_id):
        return {'program': <some logic to return your Program object>}
```

Your main template:

```
{%load my-template-tags%}

<div id="my-div">
     {%get_program program_id %}
</div>
```

And your template file:

```
{{ program.name }}
{% for process in program.process_set.all %}
    {{ process.name }}
    {% for step in process.step_set.all %}
        {{ step.name }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for control in process.control_set.all %}
        {{ control.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

You'd have to pass in your program_id to the main template.

Comment: Hi, but in this case the template file is still static. I try to get it generated based on a nested structure (tuple or dict) representing a sub-set of the entire data model. See my following edit of the original post, I think I got a step closer in the meantime.